# adjusting appendix title/ suppressing "Appendix A" title

Tags: formatting, appendices

I am trying to adjust the formatting for my appendix chapters.  I am using a document class specific to my school, but many TeX suggestions for articles and reports seem to work.

I use the following commands:

```
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1 title}
text
\chapter{chapter 2 title}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix chapter title 1}
text
\chapter{Appendix chapter title 2}
text
\end{document}
```

The titles for the appendices appear as:

### Appendix A

#### Appendix chapter title 1

### Appendix B

#### Appendix chapter title 2

What I'd like to do is suppress the "Appendix A" and "Appendix B" or alter them.  that is, I'd like the title of the appendix to appear:

### Appendix chapter title 1

### Appendix chapter title 2

However, I'd like to maintain the number of figures and tables within the appendix.  I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to do this!

Comment: you want number of figures A.1 or just 1

Answer (score 2):

Here a complete code, thanks to Christian Hupfer

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1 title}
text
\chapter{chapter 2 title}

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix chapter title 1}
\stepcounter{chapter}
\section{title 1}
text
\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
image
\caption{Appendix}
\end{figure}
\chapter*{Appendix chapter title 2}
\stepcounter{chapter}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit on your answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i will try

Comment: I meant: Wrap a 'full' document around it ;-) I had your answer in the Low-Quality-Queue, but declined to vote for delete (But I will delete this comment after elaboration ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer really I didn't understand your last comment, I trust in you, if you can edit my answer (+1) if you want me to delete it just ask. I think this is what the OP ask for and this is the simplest way i know to do.

Comment: Just `\documentclass{...}` ... `\begin{document}...\end{document}`, perhaps with a screen shot ;-)

Comment: Thank you!  This solution worked very well!  It deletes the appendix title from the table of contents, so I added the line: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix Chapter title 1}` just after `\stepcounter{chapter}`

Comment: @user77466 or `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}Appendix Chapter title 1}` if you want the number in table of contents

Answer (score 2):

This removes the (huge) space above the chapter title as well as the chapter leadin for appendix chapters (i.e. the `Appendix A` stuff)

It requires the output of the appendix number however. I will add this after the next edit.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{\typeout{Success}}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}{}{%
\typeout{removed title}}{}%
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}{\Huge \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter~#1\par\nobreak}{%
\typeout{Changed title}}{}%
}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter 1 title}
text
\chapter{chapter 2 title}

\appendix
\appendixheaderoff
\chapter{chapter title 1}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
text
\chapter{chapter title 2}
text

\chapter{chapter title 3}
text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the OP want this,the 3 rd `\xpatchcmd` not necessary no?

Comment: The 3rd `\xpatchcmd` is perhaps not necessary, but the appendix number should appear anyway, I believe. Since the Appendix title vanished, there is no further information on the appendix number left

Comment: well, you are right.