# 'Appendix A' in chapter title, but on one line

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, appendices

I have the following document. I'd like Appendix titles to be marked with the word 'Appendix', which the following achieves:

```
\documentclass[
chapterprefix=false,
appendixprefix=true, % Appendix 
numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\appendix
\chapter{AAA}
XX
\end{document}
```

But I'd like the titles to be on the same line as 'Appendix A' etc. I know how to achieve this for the whole document's chapter titles:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}%
}
\makeatother
```

But this overrides `chapterprefix=false`. How can I have this `\chapterformat` only apply to the appendix?

Comment: Try the `appendix` package which provides a lot of options and see this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242010/89098

Comment: Of course, you can move your redefinition of `\chapterformat` to just after `\appendix`, making it only apply from that point onward.

Comment: @Werner that has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is (re-)defining `\appendixmore`:

```
\documentclass[
    numbers=noenddot,
]{scrreprt}

\providecommand*\appendixmore{}
\renewcommand*\appendixmore{%
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
      \mbox{\appendixname~\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\appendix
\chapter{AAA}
XX
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that option `appendixprefix` defines and uses `\appendixmore` too. So the redefinition of `\appendixmore` disables option `appendixprefix=true`.

Another possiblity is patching `\appendix`:

```
\documentclass[
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
      \mbox{\appendixname~\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}%
    }%
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\appendix
\chapter{AAA}
XX
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.